# How to find text

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

How to extract text mentioned in below html tag

```
<div align="left" id="M_NavigationTreeQuotationIDStatus">
<div id="NavigationTreeQuotationIDStatus_1" 
igtag="7db24487-858e-4ae3-aef7-acb894ca50bb">
<div class="alignLeft"><span>USA2016001749TST<br>In progress&nbsp;
<span class="icon contextMenu"></span></span></div></div></div>
```

I want to extract text USA2016001749TST and In Progress to assert it further

Comment: Please add the following information to the question: 1. What type of solution are you looking for - xpath/identification only or code based also? 2. If code based, what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

steps to follow:

1. Identify the element using xpath `//div[@id='NavigationTreeQuotationIDStatus_1']/div/span` and store it in `element`
2. Use WebElement property text to retrive the value:
   `element.text` (in python)
   `element.getText()`  (in java)

It gives complete string "USA2016001749TST In progress"

Comment: How to trim the text to just say USA2016001749TST

Comment: you can use the language (java, python etc.) built-in options once the text is retrieved, like, split using space or get substring using index. what is the value you are getting for text? store it in a String variable. specify the language you are using and the text being retrieved

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have all the Setups of Selenium Webdriver is done earlier.

1. First of all you have to capture the xpath for the particular element. Your xpath would be something like this.

   ```
   xpath_you_captured = //div[@id="NavigationTreeQuotationIDStatus_1"]/div/span
   ```
2. Also assuming you have the WebDriver object created earlier and it is "driver". You have to do it as,

   ```
   String dataFetched =driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath_you_captured").getText();
   ```

Using the data stored, you could assert further